# Results of a query not showing up. says "Commands completed successfully"

Tags: sql-server-2012, management-studio-express

I have a small query that needs print the results in the results pane. 
The query runs fine without any errors. But I don't see the output of the query in results pane. All other select statements show the results in the results pane. Just this query is not showing up the results.
In the query option-->Query Results-->SQL sever--> Default destination to "Results to Grid" is already selected.

```
DECLARE @Start int
SET @Start = 45

WHILE (@Start <=5)
BEGIN
     PRINT CHAR(@Start)
    SET @Start = @Start+1
 END
```

Comment: Because initial value of @Start (45)  bigger than 5

Comment: Thank You. Typo from my side. I wanted to put 55 and instead type 5.